# I have 3 elements with tabindex set, there is an invisible 4th element before it loops back to the first one. What is it?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't find what is taking the focus before the loop begins again after the third element in the index. Example:

```
Input 1 - tabindex="1" --> Press tab -->
Input 2 - tabindex="2" --> Press tab -->
Input 3 - tabindex="3" --> Press tab (should bring me back to one I would think but instead...) --> 
??????? - tabindex="?" --> Press tab (and after tabbing away from the mystery element I'm back at tabindex 1") --> 
Input 1 - tabindex="1" --> Tab
```

I'm open to plain HTML solutions or javascript. I just don't know what is taking the focus. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's the body element, which I suspected but didn't know how to prove. I was able to prove it in console with:

```
document.activeElement
```

Still not sure how to prevent focus on it though.

Comment: if you dont want element to be focused by tab u can use tabindex="-1"

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that, which I should have mentioned. The body element is still a tab-focusable element though.